# NAN values when trying to get the rolling correlation

Tags: python, statistics, anaconda, jupyter, correlation

I am trying to get the rolling correlation for 2 values and I keep getting NAN values. I know that NAN values are associated with the window size but I am confused. How do I know what to put for the window size? I have looked at some prior posts on this forum regarding this issue but I am confused.

the dataset name is `ok` and here is the code that I have inserted `ok[matic].rolling(50).corr(ok[bi])` .

That is the code that I have tried; `matic` and `bi` are the two variables that I want to run a running correlation with; there are a total of 49 rows and there two columns. I do have the dates on each row. But I keep getting NAN values and I have tried inserting the number 50, 49, and 48 in the window size. I have also deleted a value from the bi variable so that it had one less than the matic value but I still received all NAN values.  I would just like a graph and a chart of each of the correlations

```py
    matic   bitcoin
Date        
2021-04-01  NaN NaN
2021-04-02  NaN NaN
2021-04-03  NaN NaN
2021-04-04  NaN NaN
2021-04-05  NaN NaN
2021-04-06  NaN NaN
2021-04-07  NaN NaN
2021-04-08  NaN NaN
2021-04-09  NaN NaN
2021-04-10  NaN NaN
2021-04-11  NaN NaN
2021-04-12  NaN NaN
2021-04-13  NaN NaN
2021-04-14  NaN NaN
```

Comment: Please be a bit more specific. What does your data structure look like? What have you tried? What libraries are you using?

Comment: Sorry, but I'm going to need a lot more info than that to be able to help you. Can you edit your post and include a small reproducible example of the error you're getting?

Comment: Ah, ok, Have you tried just doing `ok['matic'].corr(ok['bi'])` ? Or maybe `ok['matic'].rolling(3).corr(ok['bi'])` ?

Comment: Clearly put, what exactly do you mean when you say that you want the "rolling correlation"? If you just want the correlation across these two variables using the entire dataset, that is going to be just one single value calculated using `ok['matic'].corr(ok['bi'])`. However, if you want the correlation observed using only three sequential observations at a time, then you can use `ok['matic'].rolling(3).corr(ok['bi'])`.

Comment: Since you only have 49 observations, it doesn't make sense to calculate a "rolling correlation" of 50 observations. You don't even have enough observations to calculate the correlation of the first group! Do you see the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why you're getting all NAs is because the window size you're using is too big.

Here's a small reproducible example:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

nobs = 49

ok = pd.DataFrame({'matic':np.random.rand(nobs),
                   'bi':np.random.rand(nobs)})

print(ok['matic'].rolling(window=50).corr(ok['bi']))
```

Since your data only has 49 observations, it is impossible to calculate the rolling average with a window of size 50.

Instead, you could do this:

```
print(ok['matic'].rolling(window=3).corr(ok['bi']))
```

That calculates the rolling average with a window size of 3 (i.e., the correlation term across three consecutive terms).

Lastly, you could also just do this:

```
print(ok['matic'].corr(ok['bi']))
```

This will calculate just one single correlation across the entire dataset.

Comment: Thanks! I thought the window size was referring to the sample size. My apologies and I appreciate the help. Your code worked!

Comment: Awesome! Great to hear. If it helped, please consider "accepting" the answer by clicking on the check mark on the left =)